Grafana Auth Proxy with Nginx and Flask redirection
I am trying to set up a Flask server page that redirect to Grafana (throught Nginx) and passing a X-WEBAUTH-USER argument to fix the user in grafana.
I tryed to pass arguments from a Flask web-page to Nginx and to use it as the X-WEBAUTH-USER header for the loading of Grafana but I get the error 'unauthorized' from Grafana.
I tested many different options, but unless the header X-WEBAUTH-USER is hardcoded in Nginx (like this:
proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER 'user';
)
it does not work
Here is the docker-compose
grafana:
image: grafana/grafana-oss:latest
networks:
network_one
environment:

- 'NO_PROXY=${NO_PROXY},nginx_service,oauth2,mongodb,grafana'
- 'no_proxy=${NO_PROXY},nginx_service,oauth2,mongodb,grafana'
- GF_SECURITY_ALLOW_EMBEDDING=true
- GF_SECURITY_CORS_ORIGIN=\*
- 'GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=${SERVER_ROOT_URL}/grafana'
- GF_USERS_ALLOW_SIGN_UP=false
- GF_USERS_AUTO_ASSIGN_ORG=true
- 'GF_USERS_AUTO_ASSIGN_ORG_ROLE=Editor'
- GF_AUTH_PROXY_ENABLED=true
- GF_AUTH_PROXY_HEADER_NAME=X-WEBAUTH-USER
- 'GF_AUTH_PROXY_HEADER_PROPERTY=username'
- GF_AUTH_PROXY_AUTO_SIGN_UP=true
- GF_HEADERS_ENCODED=false

The Nginx api.conf
server {
location / {
resolver 127.0.0.11 ipv6=off;
proxy_pass http://flask:5000;
}

    location /grafana/{
        proxy_pass http://grafana:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-WEBAUTH-USER $arg_user;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
    } 

}

The Flask Route

@app.route('/redirection_to_grafana')
def redirection_to_grafana():
    user = 'jonah'
    return redirect(f'/grafana/?user={user}')

